# Align list items to the top

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-lists, vertical-alignment

I have a list of items that I'd like to align by the top image, instead if the bottom text as it is currently doing.

Here is how it appears:

[image: screenshot]

Is there a simple way that this is achieved in CSS? I am using Bootstrap, if there is a way to do that also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically align <li> elements in <ul>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400548/how-to-vertically-align-li-elements-in-ul)

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645360/vertical-align-text-on-inline-list-items

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209363/how-to-vertically-align-items-in-horizontally-ul-list-with-images

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're asking for is actually the default behaviour...

```
<div class="containerI">
  <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
    <h3 class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></h3><!-- put your image here instead of h3+glyphicon if you're using a jpg -->
    <p>Simple Visa Card
  </p></div>
```

**DEMO: http://www.bootply.com/KEN4TgnX0f**

Is it possible you've got some custom CSS affecting this?